# Get principal user object in service methods

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

In my spring MVC application i want to access `Principal` object created by spring security in my service layer. I thought about injecting it in my service classes, but I am sure it will not be thread safe.
Other option I am thinking, is to pass it to all service methods as argument but this do not look very clean to me.
What would be the better way to do this?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I think that the best approach would be to use the [`SecurityContextHolder`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/context/SecurityContextHolder.html).

```
Principal principal = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
```

Spring explains how it works in the [documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/technical-overview.html):

> The most fundamental object is SecurityContextHolder. This is where we
>   store details of the present security context of the application,
>   which includes details of the principal currently using the
>   application. By default the SecurityContextHolder uses a ThreadLocal
>   to store these details, which means that the security context is
>   always available to methods in the same thread of execution, even if
>   the security context is not explicitly passed around as an argument to
>   those methods. Using a ThreadLocal in this way is quite safe if care
>   is taken to clear the thread after the present principal's request is
>   processed. Of course, Spring Security takes care of this for you
>   automatically so there is no need to worry about it.

Since it uses a `ThreadLocal` to store the current authentication, you will not have any thread safety problem.